# Dynamically import modules into module based on `forRoot` config

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have a module that uses `AgmCoreModule`. It takes the `apiKey` applied on the `forRoot` and adds it `AgmCoreModule` via `LAZY_MAPS_API_CONFIG`:

```js
...some_module.ts

export const AgmCoreModuleForRoot = AgmCoreModule.forRoot()


imports: [
 AgmCoreModuleForRoot,
]
providers: [
    {
      provide: LAZY_MAPS_API_CONFIG,
      useClass: GoogleMapsConfigService,
      deps: [GoogleMapsConfigServiceConfig],
    },
  ],

export class SomeModule {
  static forRoot(
    config?: GoogleMapsConfigServiceConfig,
  ): ModuleWithProviders<SomeModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: SomeModule,
      providers: [{ provide: GoogleMapsConfigServiceConfig, useValue: config }],
    };
  }
}
```

The module is mostly made of components that do not need `AgmCoreModule` so `SomeModule` can be imported with a blank forRoot like `SomeModule.forRoot()`.

However, I'm running into issues using `SomeModule` with applications that have `AgmCoreModule` imported in a higher module say `App.module`. And that overrites the `AgmCoreModule`'s `forRoot`.

example:

```js
...app.module
imports:[
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: environment.googleApiKey,
      libraries: ['places'],
    }),

...downstream.module.ts
imports: [
SomeModule.forRoot() <-- This overwrites the above apiKey making the google places api not work
```

I would like to have the flexibility to conditionally load the `AgmCoreModule` based on the existence of an apiKey in the `forRoot` of `SomeModule`.

Is this even a thing?

Comment: you should use forRoot only once per application preferably AppModule or CoreModule in other cases where you just need component you use SomeModule without calling forRoot

Comment: `SomeModule` can be loaded any where. It must have a `forRoot` in order to pass that data to the Google places module.

Comment: hmm did you read this? https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/modules/agmcoremodule "Please use this method when you register the module at the root level." you don't need to use forRoot in each place you need to use AgmCoreModule just in root usually CoreModule or AppModule in other places you use that module without forRoot

Comment: Please stop trying to rewrite the use case...

This module is an external library, where I don't know if `AgmCoreModule` is loaded or not, outside of the existence of the `forRoot` on `SomeModule`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your `AgmCoreModule` but have you tried doing something like the below to prevent reimporting the core modules?

```ts
// module-import.guard.ts
export function throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule: any, moduleName: string) {
  if (parentModule) {
    throw new Error(`${moduleName} has already been loaded, import Core modules in the AppModule only.`);
  }
}

// agm-core.module.ts
export class AgmCoreModule{
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: AgmCoreModule) {
    throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'AgmCoreModule');
  }
}
```

As for your `api` key overwriting situation, can you not just wrap it to return something else if the config is not there? Or does `SomeModule` need to communicate with GoogleMapsConfigService, if not then maybe something like the below might help you:

```ts
export class SomeModule {
  static forRoot(config?: GoogleMapsConfigServiceConfig): ModuleWithProviders<SomeModule> {
    
    if(config) {
      return {
        ngModule: SomeModule,
        providers: [{ provide: GoogleMapsConfigServiceConfig, useValue: config }],
      };
    }
    
    return {
      ngModule: SomeModule
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not wanting to throw an error. I'm wanting to `SomeModule` to remove `AgmCoreModule` from it's imports.



Little backstory, `SomeModule` is a publishable library. So it'll not always know the `apiKey`.

Comment: And I've tried the 2nd method. Unfortunately the `AgmCoreModule` key is overwritten by the existence of `SomeModule` So just returning `SomeModule` means there is no api key. And google maps refuses to work.